# Nested list of dictionary with nested list of dictionary into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nested-lists

I need help with converting a nested list of dictionaries with a nested list of dictionaries inside of it to a dataframe. At the end, I want something that looks like (the dots are for other columns in between):

```
    id       | isbn     | isbn13      | .... | average_rating|
    30278752 |1594634025|9781594634024| .... |3.92           |
    34006942 |1501173219|9781501173219| .... |4.33           |
```

```py
    review_stat =[{'books': [{'id': 30278752,
                              'isbn': '1594634025',
                              'isbn13': '9781594634024',
                              'ratings_count': 4832,
                              'reviews_count': 8435,
                              'text_reviews_count': 417,
                              'work_ratings_count': 2081902,
                              'work_reviews_count': 3313007,
                              'work_text_reviews_count': 109912,
                             'average_rating': '3.92'}]},
                 {'books': [{'id': 34006942,
                             'isbn': '1501173219',
                             'isbn13': '9781501173219',
                             'ratings_count': 4373,
                             'reviews_count': 10741,
                             'text_reviews_count': 565,
                             'work_ratings_count': 1005504,
                             'work_reviews_count': 2142280,
                             'work_text_reviews_count': 75053,
                             'average_rating': '4.33'}]}]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you key is always `books`

`pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i['books']) for i in review_stat])`

```
         id        isbn         isbn13  ratings_count  reviews_count  text_reviews_count  work_ratings_count  work_reviews_count  work_text_reviews_count average_rating
0  30278752  1594634025  9781594634024           4832           8435                 417             2081902             3313007                   109912           3.92
0  34006942  1501173219  9781501173219           4373          10741                 565             1005504             2142280                    75053           4.33
```

You can always reset the index if you need

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) here:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(review_stat, 'books')
```

[out]

```
         id        isbn  ... work_text_reviews_count  average_rating
0  30278752  1594634025  ...                  109912            3.92
1  34006942  1501173219  ...                   75053            4.33
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe a faster way without needing to `append` dataframes is to "flatten" the lists, because the dictionary contains single-key `books` which also contains one element. Therefore, it should easy to flatten into a single list which can be passed to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x['books'][0] for x in review_stat])
```

Outputs:

```
             id        isbn  ... work_text_reviews_count  average_rating
0  30278752  1594634025  ...                  109912            3.92
1  34006942  1501173219  ...                   75053            4.33
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
d=[i['books'][0] for i in review_stat]

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```